# Error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.localhost inside GetServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, subdomain, next.js13

Why am I receiving the following error when trying to make some calls within the getServerSideProps itself? I get this error message as a response.
[image]

App url: http://localhost:3000
Api url: http://api.localhost:3001